# Meteor Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm getting 2 errors with my meteor app. These are the errors below. I'm using accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 and I'm trying to display my header template inside `layout.html`.

Here are my 2 errors with some code.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Uncaught Error: There are multiple templates named 'layout'. Each template needs a unique name.
```

^^Even though I only have one template named layout.

Code:

**layout.html**

```
 <template name="layout">
   <div class="container">
     {{>header}}
     <div id="main" class="row-fluid">
     {{>yield}}
     </div>
   </div>
 </template>
```

**header.html**

```
<template name="header">
   <header class="navbar">
     <div class="navbar-inner">
       <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </a>
       <a class="brand" href="{{pathFor 'postsList'}}">Test</a>
       <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
         <ul class="nav pull-right">
           <li>{{> loginButtons}}</li>
         </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</template>
```

Why isn't it displaying the loginbuttons?

**Router.js**

```
Router.configure({
 layoutTemplate: 'layout',
 loadingTemplate: 'loading',
 waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('posts'); }
});
Router.map(function() {
 this.route('postsList', {path: '/'});

 this.route('postPage', {
    path: '/posts/:_id',
    data: function() { return Posts.findOne(this.params._id); }
 });
});
```

Comment: Whats your router.js look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use mrt:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 or ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3? if you use mrt:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3, it won't work because not supported anymore. Use ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the `li` element for the login buttons. Change your header inclusion to look like this `{{> header}}`, notice the little caret.

EDIT:

Instead of using a `Router.map` try using `Router.route` like this:

```
Router.route('/', {
  name: 'postsList' 
});

Router.route({'/posts/:_id',
  name: 'postPage',
  data: function() {
    return Posts.findOne(this.params._id);
  }
});
```

Comment: When I add that my screen disappears even though what you're saying is right

Comment: Thats weird... check out my edit maybe that will help.

Comment: Getting an error in the console now when I done that

Comment: `Router.configure({
layoutTemplate:'layout',
loadingTemplate:'loading',
waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('posts'); }
});Router.map(function(){this.route('postsList', {path: '/'});
this.route('postPage', {path: '/posts/:_id',data: function() { return Posts.findOne(this.params._id); }});});Router.configure({layoutTemplate:'layout',loadingTemplate:'loading',waitOn:function(){returnMeteor.subscribe('posts');}});Router.map(function() {
 this.route('postsList', {path: '/'});
 this.route('postPage', {path: '/posts/:_id',
  data: function(){return Posts.findOne(this.params._id);}
 });
});`